# SQL Server statement is not returning anything

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two table call User_History and List_Of_Event.

I'm trying to get all the result from User_History table like this but I'm not sure why it's not showing me anything If my Event_ID column in User_History table is blank.

I'm just wondering how can I still get all the result even if my Event_Id column in User_History table is all blank/empty.

```
Select Event_Name As 'Event', GIN, GID, UPN, OneDrive, SharePoint, Mailbox, Event_Date, Extra 
From List_of_Events E 
Inner Join User_History H 
  on E.Event_Id = H.Event_Id
```

```
List_Of_Event have Event_Id (int) and Event_Name (varchar)
User_History have Event_Id(int) and other Varchar columns
```

Comment: What's in `List_of_Events` and `User_History`  tables? a quick guess would be try a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @Andrew I think Right Join is what I'm looking for but still thanks for the help.

Comment: If you provide example ddl and dml it will be much simpler to demonstrate both what you want, and for us to demonstrate how to get there. It's likely what you need to use is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but without the example to understand the relationship its hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 3):

then you need a left join to `list of events` table :

```
Select Event_Name As 'Event'
      , GIN, GID, UPN
      , OneDrive, SharePoint
      , Mailbox, Event_Date, Extra 
From User_History H 
left Join List_of_Events E 
  on E.Event_Id = H.Event_Id
```

Comment: I think Right Join is what I'm looking for but still thanks for the help.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN is a bad variation of LEFT JOIN because it's harder to understand and has no advantage.